# Android Studio - SequencePluginReload requires unknown plugin

Tags: android-studio, plugins

In Android Studio 1.5.1, I'm trying to run the plugin SequencePluginReload 1.0.6. The installation works fine, but after restarting Android studio I get the following error message:

> Problems found loading plugins: Plugin "SequencePluginReload" was not loaded: required plugin "com.intellij.diagram" not installed.

So I figured, I need to install the com.intellij.diagram plugin. However, I wasn't able to find it in the android studio repository or elsewhere. Any ideas where I could find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be resolved in the latest version.
For me, that is Android Studio 2.1.1 with SequenceDiagram 1.1. (They renamed the project)